# Google Map API - infowindow in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, razor, google-maps-api-3

Hello I'm retrieving data from SqlServerCe so I created foreach loop to create markers - that works it creates multiple markers but now I wanted to add to each of these marker an infowindow. But now whenever I click on marker the infowindow pops-up on the lastly created marker.

```
<script>
function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
        zoom:5,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
      , mapProp);

    $(function () {
 @foreach (var row in data)
 {
   <text>
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(@row.GeoLat,  @row.GeoLong),
            map: map });

        marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "test"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            marker.info.open(map, marker);
        });

        </text>


 }
    });
}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

May someone help me with adding infowindow to each created markers?

Thank you for your responding and your time.

This is how I load from SqlServerCe

```
var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");

var data = db.Query("SELECT DescriptionService,GeoLong,GeoLat FROM services");
var array = new []{data} ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following, written in javascript

```
var infoWindowContent = [];
for(var index=0; index< places.length; index++){
        infoWindowContent[index] = getInfoWindowDetails(places[index]);
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(places[index].latitude,places[index].longitude);
        bounds.extend(location);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position    : location,
            map         : map,
            title       : places[index].title
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker,index){
            return function(){
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[index]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                map.setZoom(15);
            }
        })(marker,index));

    }   


    function getInfoWindowDetails(location){
        var contentString = '<div id="content" style="width:270px;height:100px">' +
                            '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + location.title + '</h3>'+
                            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                                '<div style="float:left;width:100%">'+ location.address + '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>';
        return contentString;
    }
```

I added an array `infoWindowContent` then added the information to the array. You can use the same logic

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know how can I load data from SqlServerCe to use it like you ? Please see my edit.

Comment: here I have created a JSON array places. Then I added the contents from that object. You can either create a JSON object and use my code there or change the code as the return value of your query

Comment: I think I understand that but may I please know what is hidden under `places` ? Is it an array in which is stored data from `SqlServerCe` ? May you please share with me code for loading data from SqlServer to array ? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @Marek: I'm not using SqlServerCe. I'm using mysql in my web app. I'm creating a JSON object from the data received from the database, the places is just an array of objects as follows `[{ title="place 1", address="my Location"}, { title="place 2", address="my Location 2 "}]`